# IdP metadata EntitiesDescriptor

Tags: metadata, keycloak, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm using the [ITfoxtec Identity SAML2](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) library with Keycloak as IdP. When requesting the IdP metadata information, the ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 library seems not to recognize the <EntitiesDescriptor> tag and expects a <EntityDescriptor> as the top level element in the metadata xml.
Use of <EntitiesDescriptor> is described in https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have released [version 4.6.2-beta1](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/4.6.2-beta1) with support for reading SAML 2.0 metadata with a EntitiesDescriptor root element. The first EntityDescriptor element is selected.

Please let me know if it works for you.